# Angular 2 View won't update until user input in another box

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, angular2-forms

I am trying to implement form validation with Reactive Forms in Angular 2. Following is the situation

There are two input boxes

Following are image examples for step 1 and step 2

[image: User enters invalid text in Box1 <-- Form error won't show up]
[image: User enters a key in Box 2 <-- Form error of Box 1 shows up]

Following is my onValueChanged function that is called from the form data subscription

```
onValueChanged(data ?: any) {
    if (!this.accountCreateForm) {
        return;
    }
    const form = this.accountCreateForm;
    this.formErrors = {}

    for (const control of WPFormUtil.getAllControls(form)) {
        if (control && control.dirty && control.touched && !control.valid) {
            const field = WPFormUtil.getControlName(control);
            // reset existing message
            this.formErrors[field] = ' ';
            const messages = this.validationMessages[field];
            for (const key in control.errors) {
                if (control.errors.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                    this.formErrors[field] += messages[key] + ' ';
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Following is the HTML which shows formErrors

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Company Name <span class="text-warning">*</span></label>
        <input formControlName="companyName" id="companyName" type="text" name="name" class="form-control required" placeholder=" ">
        <label *ngIf="formErrors.companyName" class="text-danger">{{ formErrors.companyName }}</label>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Street Address <span class="text-warning">*</span></label>
        <input formControlName="street1" id="streetAddress1" type="text" name="name" class="form-control required" placeholder="Street 1">
        <label *ngIf="formErrors.street1" class="text-danger">{{ formErrors.street1 }}</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

**What I am expecting ?**

The formError for companyName should display immediately when an invalid character is entered or on blur.

Answer (score 1):

The keypresses should be caught without e.g blur event. Here's a simple example, using `valueChanges` with some modifications on your `onValueChanged` method. Not knowing what is *invalid* characters is in your case, here I have put that company name only accepts numbers. Please refer to the example and adjust your code accordingly :)

The validation:

```ts
companyName: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('^\\d+$')]],
```

Subscribe to changes:

```ts
this.accountCreateForm.valueChanges
  .subscribe(data => this.onValueChanged(this.accountCreateForm));
```

Validate form fields:

```ts
onValueChanged(forms: any) {
    if (!forms) { return; }
    const form = forms;

    for (const field in this.formErrors) {
        // clear previous error message (if any)
        this.formErrors[field] = '';
        const control = form.get(field);

        if (control && control.dirty && !control.valid) {
            const messages = this.validationMessages[field];
            for (const key in control.errors) {
                this.formErrors[field] += messages[key] + ' ';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And then your form errors and validation messages:

```ts
formErrors = {
    'street1': '',
    'companyName': '',
};

validationMessages = {
    'street1': {
        'required': 'required',
    },
    'companyName': {
        'required': 'required',
        'pattern': 'Company name is invalid'
    },
}
```

This works like a charm:

### [Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/cgSyv0ffNqeXaGA40uq5?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

if you want a live update you have to use onKeyUp function and onChange. the change handler is called in the moment you leave the field (can't comment. sorry)

Comment: How do I use them with a Angular2 reactive form ?

Comment: This is not true, if you subscribe to `valueChanges`, each keypress is catched.